# How to encode Post Data JSON in CloseableHttpClient APi

Tags: java, rest, post

I have used the CloseableHttpClient APi for a Post call and Basic Auth for authorisation

```
private CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://example.com");

MyJson myJson = new MyJson(); //custom java object to be posted as Request Body
Gson gson = new Gson();
String param = gson.toJson(myJson);
StringEntity urlparam = new StringEntity(param);

String credentials = username + ":" + passwprd;
String base64Credentials = new String(Base64.getencoder().encode(credentials.getBytes()));
String authorizartionHeader = "Basic" + base64Credentials;


httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/Json");
httppost.setHeader("Authorization", authorizartionHeader);
urlparam.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(urlparam);
httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I am getting error

> "Invalid UTF-8 middle byte"

I have encoded the JSON still the encoding is not working for other locales except English. How to encode the Post data.

I tried using the method
`httppost.setEntity(new URLEncodedFormEntity(namevaluePair, "UTF-8"))` but I don't have any Namevaluepair and if the add the Username-pswd in that then getting Null pointer response.

Comment: Have you tried setting StringEntity as UTF 8 ? `new StringEntity(param, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` ?

And adding header ? `.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to set everything as UTF-8

```
StringEntity urlparam = new StringEntity(param, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

And add proper header

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```